# Execute script with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, daemon

I want to start my daemon with my application.

In the command line, I can write something like `lib/daemons/mydaemon_ctl start` to start up my daemon, but I have to do this manually. I want the daemon to start when I start my server (i.e. when the initializer files are loaded).

Is there a ruby command for executing a command line?
Something like `exec "lib/daemons/mydaemon_ctl start"`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you just want to run shell commands in ruby code, well you can use **system** or backtick(`)

```
system 'ls' # will return ls output in *nix
`dir` # will return dir output in windows
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I'm looking for.
Turns out the daemon keeps running even when the server stops. Where would I put a command that I want to run when the server stops? (to stop the daemon?) Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry not sure how to do that after server stops.

Comment: Posted a separate question. Thank you very much!