# How to delete a file from the file system using ruby on rails 2.3.9 and ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io

The files are saved to public/data using:

```
def upload_vault_data        
    if params[:dump][:file]
        uploaded_io = params[:dump][:file]
        File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'data', "data_#{session[:campaign_id]}_#{uploaded_io.original_filename}"), 'w') do |file|
            file.write(uploaded_io.read)
        end
    end
end
```

This works as expected, but how to let the user delete the file once it has been uploaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails allows you to execute system commands using the method called "system".

eg.

```
system 'ls'
```

More info here: [Execute script with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947180/execute-script-with-ruby-on-rails)

In your case, you can probably do a

```
system "rm #{path-to-my-file}"
```

Comment: But as Ryan has mentioned, there are many elegant solutions available to handle file uploads. You should definitely check them out...

Answer (score 3):

To delete file using rails use

File.delete("Path of file").

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at using something such as [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly), [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) to handle file uploads in your application, rather than hand-coding this.